# Securely store In-App Purchases

Tags: ios, security, encryption, app-store, in-app-purchase

I'm implementing In-App Purchase in my application but I have a problem I could not solve.
For the implentation I read several tutorials, but all of these use the same system to save if you have purchased a product or not.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool: YES forKey:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
```

It's simple, but insecure. With an iPad without a Jailbreak I managed to change the value from FALSE to TRUE without special skills.

So, is there a simple way to encrypt this data? Another alternative?

Comment: Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064144/correct-and-secure-manner-of-storing-in-app-purchases) for some insights

Comment: possible duplicate of [Secure way to unlock full version via In-App Purchase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138730/secure-way-to-unlock-full-version-via-in-app-purchase)

Answer (score 0):

You should store that kind of information in your server and ensure your app communicates securely with it.

Comment: But I need to quickly check if purchased or not and communication with the server will not be as fast.